# Using HttpPost HttpClient at API level 25

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I want to user HttpPost, HttpClient etc at API level 25 but it is giving warning

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

I have tried everything and searched about it a lot but this dependency warning is not getting removed

My build.gradle is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "smartpark.park.com.smartpark"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.8.0'

// UiAutomatorTesting
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
}
```

I know I can use HttpUrlConnection or URLConnection but I want to use this only.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those components are deprecated. Is there a specific reason why you want to use only those?

Comment: Yes I know they are depricated. But i want to use it as in some authentication it is only required